# Interceptor not called with anotated JPA entity

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Interceptor annotation definition:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface EntityChange {
}
```

Interceptor definition:

```
@Interceptor
@Priority(1)
@EntityChange
public class DataChangeInterceptor implements Serializable {      

 @AroundInvoke
    public Object method(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {...
```

Usage of annotation within entity:

```
@Entity
public class entity implements Serializable {

...
    @EntityChange
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
...
```

setId method should trigger the AOP method. But it does not. In case I annotate a method from a bean it gets triggered.

The reason is in my opinion that entity is not inside the EJB context(it is not an EJB bean). The question is, how to make the method trigger the interceptor the correct way. (imho it is not correct to make from an entity EJB bean)

Comment: Why don't you use a JPA entity listener instead of an EJB listener?

Comment: @BalusC is it possible to create my own listener? Trigger should be on detached entity when field get changed? The predefined EntityListeners does not fits my need. (Does not necessary needs to be entity. Can be DTO.)